# Hierarchical Kendo UI Grid Export to Export

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Need to export hierarchical grids in Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC with all the info in a single document

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: In Hierarchical Kendo grid, I am not able to export all the info in a single document.

Comment: are you trying to export just a .csv or does it have to be an .xlsx file?

Comment: .xlsx file @BillRuhl

Comment: What is the result you get when you use kendo's default export functionality? Is the child grid not being included or? Please provide example of the result after export, as well as your code